# Sections changing top dynamically with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.top-section {
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}

.card-header {
  position: relative;
  height: 175px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  @include border-radius(4px 4px 0 0);
  margin: .5rem;
}

.card {
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  .card-img-top {
    padding: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 0rem;
  }
  .card-block {
    position: relative;
    padding: 2rem;
  }
  .card-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .card-title {
    text-align: center !important;
    line-height: 1rem
  }
}

.col-md-4 .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 10rem !important;
}

.other {
position:relative;
top:840px;
background:blue;
}

.other_2{
position:relative;
top:840px;
background:pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>
<section id="intro" class="top-section">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="height:250px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3>Lorepsum Text Lorepsum Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-full" style="top:15%; position:relative !important; background:transparent">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img-top">
              <img class='img-responsive' src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/800x400" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">TITLE</h4>
              <hr>
              <p class="card-text"> Magni inventore repellat dignissimos eveniet dolore ex sit illo adipisci accusamus quos</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img-top">
              <img class='img-responsive' src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/800x400" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">TITLE</h4>
              <hr>
              <p class="card-text"> Magni inventore repellat dignissimos eveniet dolore ex sit illo adipisci accusamus quos</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img-top">
              <img class='img-responsive' src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/800x400" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">TITLE</h4>
              <hr>
              <p class="card-text"> Magni inventore repellat dignissimos eveniet dolore ex sit illo adipisci accusamus quos</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="background:black; height:100% !important">blabla</div>
</section>
<section class="other">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    This is another section and I should be always adjust and be below the videos on any screen resolution.
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="other_2">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    This is another section and I should be always below blue seciton
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I achieve something similar to the image attached with bootstrap?

I'd like to have the cards, floating between sections 1 and 2, to contain videos. My problem is that I need section 2 to be larger when the cards will stack, so that there is a space between the bottom of the cards and beginning of section 2.

[image: Layout]

Comment: share your code

Comment: can you show us your actual output ? I want to see how it differs from the image you linked

Comment: Just added a snippet, notice how there is a blue and pink section that instead of being below the video card section they are on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexbox and positioning of the three smaller divs.
See my code example:

```css
#divTop {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#divMiddle {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
}

#divA, #divB, #divC {
  background-color: #e9c9c9;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: 20%;
  
}

#divBottom1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#divBottom2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div id="divTop" class="col-xs-12"></div>
 
<div id="divMiddle" class="col-xs-12">
  
 <div id="divA">Div A</div>
 <div id="divB">Div B</div>
 <div id="divC">Div C</div>
 
</div>

<div id="divBottom1" class="col-xs-12"></div>
<div id="divBottom2" class="col-xs-12"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS code solution:**

Define those div elements to be `position:absolute;` out of the normal flow of the document, but `relative` to it's container; then give them heights that exceed the container, align, *etc*. And then with the container element apply: `overflow: visible;` depending on your content beneath you may also have to toggle these element's, or the content element below's `z-index` [**property**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

**For a pure template bootstrap solution:**

Research to find bootstraps equivalent to the above then tweak as needed.

Comment: could you show an example with the code snippet provided?